# LVM tries to de-activate in use volume at shutdown and partition alignment concerns

Tags: partitioning, lvm, fdisk

Is it okay to have root file system on a lvm2 logical volume? Because, I always get the following error on every time I reboot or shutdown the machine.

`Can't deactivate volume group "vgSystem" with 1 open logical volume(s)` **failed**
`will now restart.`

*vgSystem* volume group contains two logical volumes, namely, *lvRoot* for root file system and *lvSwap* for swap.

Although, it has no effect on booting on next time, personally I don not like to see warning messages in **Red** letters, especially the one which says *failed*. So can someone help me regarding this issue.

In case if you want to know my partition structure, here it is...

`Disk /dev/sda: 247.0 GB, 246960619520 bytes`
`255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30024 cylinders`
`Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes`
`Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes`
`I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes`
`Disk identifier: 0x0000993f`

`Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System`

`/dev/sda1   *           1         122      975872   83  Linux`

`Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.`

`/dev/sda2             122        3648    28320768   8e  Linux LVM`

`/dev/sda3            3648       30025   211873792   8e  Linux LVM`

On side question:  How to avoid the statement *Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary* is appearing when partitioning using **fdisk** (i.e. how to partition correctly so that the above statement does not appear)

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the shutdown script is being a little indiscriminate in managing LVM. In short, you have nothing to fear, you won't be able to deactivate an LVM volume while it's in use.

Your second question is much more complicated. It amounts to aligning your partitions correctly depending on the sector size of your disk. Here's a [good article from IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw074KB-Disksdth-LX) to get you started. It's not fatal, though it will impact performance some. Unless you're running a production server, or you're really into tweaking, I would leave it alone.

Comment: The link you have given is quite useful. It is a good starting point. Thanks for the effort and information :)